# Getting "More than one input with id content" in yesod-test response

Tags: yesod, yesod-forms

I'm following [Esposito's Yesod tutorial](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Yesod-tutorial-for-newbies/) and trying to put a test around the Mirror example.

My test is cribbed from the `HomeTest.hs` file included from `yesod init`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module MirrorTest
    ( mirrorSpecs
    ) where

import TestImport
import qualified Data.List as L

mirrorSpecs :: Spec
mirrorSpecs =
    ydescribe "This tests the sample mirror feature" $ do

        yit "loads the mirror page and checks it has correct elements" $ do
            get MirrorR
            statusIs 200
            htmlAllContain "h1" "Mirror test"
            htmlAllContain "label" "Enter your text"

            request $ do
                setMethod "POST"
                setUrl MirrorR
                byLabel "Enter your text" "wooo"

            statusIs 200
            printBody
            htmlCount ".p" 1
            htmlAllContain ".h1" "You posted"
            htmlAllContain ".p" "woooooow"
            htmlAllContain ".p" "text/plain"
```

Meanwhile my `mirror.hamlet` file is:

```
<h1> Mirror test
<form method=post action=@{MirrorR}>
    <label for=content>Enter your text
    <input type=text name=content>
    <input type=submit>
```

But the test output I am getting is:

```
1) This tests the sample mirror feature loads the mirror page and checks it has correct elements
More than one input with id content
```

I'm confused: only one input has the *name* of content, while more than one element has that name, but as far as I recall names are not necessarily unique (different from actual *ids*). Am I going to need to use [Yesod.Test.TransversingCSS](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-test-1.2.3.1/docs/Yesod-Test-TransversingCSS.html) just to accomplish what I want to do here, by giving the input an actual id?

My Haskell is still pretty weak, so I may be missing the obvious, and examples of how to implement tests in Yesod are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the same error message you do. Instead, the error message I see is:

> No input with id content

This may be due to differing yesod-form versions. This error message is completely accurate, and indicates a real error. The `for` attribute of a label refers to a tag's `id`, not its `name`. Please try setting the `id` attribute on your `input` to `content` and see if that solves your problems.

Comment: Oh my gosh! You're totally right. Thank you for helping me see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, my solution is to ignore trying to actually use the form from the first GET request (as I would approach it with, say, Capybara) and instead I am just shunting params directly to the POST submitting my form would do. This is what is passing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module MirrorTest
    ( mirrorSpecs
    ) where

import TestImport
import qualified Data.List as L

mirrorSpecs :: Spec
mirrorSpecs =
    ydescribe "This tests the sample mirror feature" $ do

        yit "loads the mirror page and checks it has correct elements" $ do
            get MirrorR
            statusIs 200
            htmlAllContain "h1" "Mirror test"
            htmlAllContain "label" "Enter your text"

            request $ do
                setMethod "POST"
                setUrl MirrorR
                addPostParam "content" "wooo"

            statusIs 200
            printBody
            htmlCount "p" 2
            htmlAnyContain "h1" "You posted"
            htmlAnyContain "p" "woooooow"
```

I'd still really like to understand how byLabel works and what I'm doing wrong in my first attempt. I'll be happy to mark a correct answer that helps.